# Yinipar's first letter with low quality when zooming in

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to quote a bible verse in two different languages and using `yinipar`. The output looks good until I zoom in to the first letter of the verse. It turns out that this big letter has a considerably low quality respect of the rest of the text and the more zoom in, the more the edges and borders look weird. The following image shows the undesired effect.
[image: First letter with fewer quality]

The question is simple. Is it possible to enhance or improve the quality of the first letter, or is it just a matter of my PDF viewer (in this case Okular)?

Here there's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,final]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=10.5cm, top=4mm, left=8mm, right=8mm, bottom=4mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgothic}
\usepackage{cinzel}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage[protrusion]{microtype}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\colorlet{Verde}{green!55!blue!80!white}
\colorlet{Amarillo}{yellow!10}

\usepackage{background}
\newcommand{\pageornament}{%

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \coordinate (SI) at ($(current page.north west) + (0.5cm,-0.5cm)$);
      \coordinate (SD) at ($(current page.north east) + (-0.5cm,-0.5cm)$);
      \coordinate (ID) at ($(current page.south east) + (-0.5cm,0.5cm)$);
      \coordinate (II) at ($(current page.south west) + (0.5cm,0.5cm)$);
      \coordinate[below right = 1mm of SI] (RSI);
      \coordinate[below left = 1mm of SD] (RSD);
      \coordinate[above right = 1mm of II] (RII);
      \coordinate[above left = 1mm of ID] (RID);
  \fill[Verde!50,rounded corners=3pt] (SI) rectangle (ID);
\fill[Amarillo,rounded corners=1.5pt] (RSD) rectangle (RII);
     \node[below right=10cm of SI, font=\Huge\calligra, gray] {};
     \node[font=\Huge, below right=5cm of SI] {};

      \node[anchor=north west] at ($(current page.north west) + (0.5cm,-0.5cm)$){%
      \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = Verde,opacity=0.5]{41}};
      \node[anchor=north east] at ($(current page.north east) + (-0.5cm,-0.5cm)$){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v,color = Verde,opacity=0.5]{41}};
      \node[anchor=south west] at ($(current page.south west) + (0.5cm,0.5cm)$){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h,color = Verde,opacity=0.5]{41}};
      \node[anchor=south east] at ($(current page.south east) + (-0.5cm,0.5cm)$){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c,color = Verde, opacity=0.5]{41}};
      \node[anchor=south] at ($(current page.south) + (0cm,0.5cm)$){%
      \pgfornament[width=0.5\textwidth,color = Verde, opacity=0.5]{88}};  
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\begin{document}
\pageornament
\vspace*{2\baselineskip}

 \begin{minipage}[l]{0.43\textwidth}
\yinipar{\color{Verde}D}{och} segen soll über alle kommen, die allein auf mich, den herrn, ihr vertrauen setzen! sie sind wie 
bäume, die am 
wasser stehen und ihre wurzeln zum bach hin ausstrecken. sie fürchten nicht die glühende hitze; ihr laub bleibt grün und frisch. selbst 
wenn der regen ausbleibt, leiden sie keine not. nie hören sie auf, frucht zu tragen.
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{-1cm}\hfil
 \begin{minipage}[r]{0.43\textwidth}
 \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\yinipar{\color{Verde}B}{endito} el varón que se fía 
en jehová, y cuya confianza es jehová. porque él será como el árbol plantado junto a las aguas, que junto a la 
corriente echará sus raíces, y no verá cuando viniere el calor, sino que su hoja estará verde; y en el año de sequía no se fatigará, ni 
dejará de hacer fruto.
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}
\begin{minipage}[l]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\small\calligra{Jeremiah 17:7-8}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[l]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\small\calligra{Jeremías 17:7-8}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\end{document}
```

Comment: you must be using xetex or luatex as you use fontspec, so don't load inputenc (it generates a warning about that)

Comment: I don't know if the initial font is available in type1 form, the original version was in metafont so bitmaps can be generated at arbitrarily high resolutions but if you decide on say 300dpi then if you scale in it will of course show the pixel resolution

Comment: Unfortunately, the `yinitas` font is only available as bitmap.

Comment: I tried not to load inputenc but the problem persists. It seems I'll have to get used to it.

Comment: inputenc isn't related to the fonts used. as you are using xe or lua tex the alternative is just to use any initial font on your system or you find on a web search for free initial fonts, unlike classic tex where metafont fonts were the main option, you can use any font you can find these days, most will be in scalable formats such as type1 or opentype

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are using xelatex you can use the otf-version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{Verde}{green!55!blue!80!white}
\newfontface\yinit{Yinit.otf}[Scale=5]
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\yinipar}[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{\yinit{#1}}%
\hangindent=\wd0\hangafter=-4\advance\hangindent by .25em
{\dimen@=-3\baselineskip
\dimen@=\baselinestretch\dimen@
\hskip-\wd0 \hskip-.25em
\raisebox{\dimen@}[0pt][0pt]{\unhbox0}\hskip.25em}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[l]{0.43\textwidth}
\yinipar{\color{Verde}D}{och} segen soll über alle kommen, die allein auf mich, den herrn, ihr vertrauen setzen! sie sind wie
bäume, die am
wasser stehen und ihre wurzeln zum bach hin ausstrecken. sie fürchten nicht die glühende hitze; ihr laub bleibt grün und frisch. selbst
wenn der regen ausbleibt, leiden sie keine not. nie hören sie auf, frucht zu tragen.
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ulrike, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the new font isn't 100% aligned with respect of the following text, as it is shown in the picture I posted above. What can I do?

Comment: I changed the scale down to 4 and it works, but I guess the font still isn't fully aligned to the text. Probably my eyes just don't realize it.

Comment: Change the scale factor, it was late and I didn't really try to optimize the size. Or use lettrine as suggested by Beenhard.

Answer (score 4):

The `yinitas` font is only available as bitmap and will be included as a Type3 font. Such fonts can be created at whatever resolution is needed, provided a suitable mode is found.

In your case it seems that 2400dpi is sufficient.

Now the problem is to persuade XeTeX into using such resolution. Here's one.

Prepare a simple file such as

```
\pdfpkmode={supre}
\pdfpkresolution=2400

\font\x=yinitas \x

A

\bye
```

and compile it with `pdftex`. This will automatically run Metafont and create a bitmap font for `yinitas` at 2400dpi.

Now run XeLaTeX on your document with

```
xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -r 2400" charlie
```

(`charlie.tex` is the name I used for my test, use the right file name, of course).

I tried with a mode supporting a much higher resolution, but `yinitas` doesn't compile.

It compiles when the mode is `linolttz` and the resolution is `3386`.

Answer (score 3):

There is now an `open type` version of the font: `yinit-otf`, so it can be used and zoomed at will with `fontspec` and `xe/lualatex`. Here is a code which uses `\lettrine` rather than the `\yinitpar` command from `yfonts`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,final]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=10.5cm, top=4mm, left=8mm, right=8mm, bottom=4mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgothic}
\usepackage{cinzel}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{lettrine}
 \usepackage[protrusion]{microtype}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\colorlet{Verde}{green!55!blue!80!white}
\colorlet{Amarillo}{yellow!10}

\usepackage{background}
\newcommand{\pageornament}{%

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \coordinate (SI) at ($(current page.north west) + (0.5cm,-0.5cm)$);
      \coordinate (SD) at ($(current page.north east) + (-0.5cm,-0.5cm)$);
      \coordinate (ID) at ($(current page.south east) + (-0.5cm,0.5cm)$);
      \coordinate (II) at ($(current page.south west) + (0.5cm,0.5cm)$);
      \coordinate[below right = 1mm of SI] (RSI);
      \coordinate[below left = 1mm of SD] (RSD);
      \coordinate[above right = 1mm of II] (RII);
      \coordinate[above left = 1mm of ID] (RID);
  \fill[Verde!50,rounded corners=3pt] (SI) rectangle (ID);
\fill[Amarillo,rounded corners=1.5pt] (RSD) rectangle (RII);
     \node[below right=10cm of SI, font=\Huge\calligra, gray] {};
     \node[font=\Huge, below right=5cm of SI] {};

      \node[anchor=north west] at ($(current page.north west) + (0.5cm,-0.5cm)$){%
      \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = Verde,opacity=0.5]{41}};
      \node[anchor=north east] at ($(current page.north east) + (-0.5cm,-0.5cm)$){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v,color = Verde,opacity=0.5]{41}};
      \node[anchor=south west] at ($(current page.south west) + (0.5cm,0.5cm)$){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h,color = Verde,opacity=0.5]{41}};
      \node[anchor=south east] at ($(current page.south east) + (-0.5cm,0.5cm)$){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c,color = Verde, opacity=0.5]{41}};
      \node[anchor=south] at ($(current page.south) + (0cm,0.5cm)$){%
      \pgfornament[width=0.5\textwidth,color = Verde, opacity=0.5]{88}};
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\newfontface\Yinit{Yinit}
\renewcommand\LettrineFontHook{\color{Verde}\Yinit}

\begin{document}

\pageornament
\vspace*{2\baselineskip}\par
 \begin{minipage}[l]{0.43\textwidth}
\lettrine{D}{och}
segen soll über alle kommen, die allein auf mich, den herrn, ihr vertrauen setzen! sie sind wie
bäume, die am
wasser stehen und ihre wurzeln zum bach hin ausstrecken. sie fürchten nicht die glühende hitze; ihr laub bleibt grün und frisch. selbst
wenn der regen ausbleibt, leiden sie keine not. nie hören sie auf, frucht zu tragen.
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{-1cm}\hfil
 \begin{minipage}[r]{0.43\textwidth}
 \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\lettrine{B}{endito} el varón que se fía
en jehová, y cuya confianza es jehová. porque él será como el árbol plantado junto a las aguas, que junto a la
corriente echará sus raíces, y no verá cuando viniere el calor, sino que su hoja estará verde; y en el año de sequía no se fatigará, ni
dejará de hacer fruto.
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}
\begin{minipage}[l]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\small\calligra{Jeremiah 17:7-8}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[l]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\small\calligra{Jeremías 17:7-8}
\end{minipage}
\hfill

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]